# Pandas sort column with numerical string

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a DataFrame below:

```
col1

Numb10
Numb11
Numb12
Numb7
Numb8
```

How can I sort with number order:

```
col1

Numb7
Numb8
Numb10
Numb11
Numb12
```

I tried but got error `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`.

```
df.sort_values(by = "col1", key = (lambda x: int(x[4:])))
```

Update with one missing in `col1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `x[4:]` might not always be integers. You can verify with

```
# convert to numerical values, float, not integers
extracted_nums = pd.to_numeric(df['col1'].str[4:], errors='coerce')

# check for invalid values
# if not `0` means you have something that are not numerical
print(extracted_nums.isna().any())

# sort by values
df.loc[extracted_nums.sort_values().index]
```

Answer (score 6):

`key` in [`sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) takes the Series as parameter instead of individual element. From the docs:

> Apply the key function to the values before sorting. This is similar to the key argument in the builtin sorted() function, with **the notable difference that this key function should be vectorized**. It should expect a Series and return a Series with the same shape as the input. It will be applied to each column in by independently.

In your case, you can use `.str` and `astype` for slicing and type convertion:

```
df.sort_values(by='col1', key=lambda s: s.str[4:].astype(int))
     col1
3   Numb7
4   Numb8
0  Numb10
1  Numb11
2  Numb12
```